# Java Android App, Send and receive variables?

Tags: java, android, get, show, send

Android java (Eclipse):

I'm a beginner at programming android apps.

I'm trying to create a test app that sends values to a php script on my wampserver and then back to my android app for display. It looks like it sends the variables to the script, but not back for display.

How do I send the values back for displaying?

PHP script:

```
<?php

 $filename="datatest.html";
 file_put_contents($filename,$_POST["id"]."<br />",FILE_APPEND);
 file_put_contents($filename,$_POST["stringdata"]."<br />",FILE_APPEND);
 $msg=file_get_contents($filename);
 echo $msg; 

 ?>
```

Android MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.phptest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void postData() {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.41:8383/android_butler/mypage.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    } 





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: For returning any result, you will have to format the data (result) in some format such as json, xml etc and read the result from Android code by XML/Json parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track for sending data to your server you can use `POST` variables.

If it gets more complex, for example sending an array then you need

For sending back you will encode PHP array into JSON data, then your app will be able to parse the json string into java objects.

Some helpful pointers:

Read up about JSON:

- http://www.json.org/java/

Some JSON libraries:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html
- https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

PHP

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

You can do the same with XML, but JSON is much simpler.

ANDROID:

One more thing, I did not see how you call this function , but in android you will need to do it in a background thread, take a look at async task:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Hope this helps

Comment: @user3888775 I added one more link for async task, please take a look